# How to get vertical slider in enaml?

Tags: python, enaml

Is it possible to do a vertical slider in enaml? I could not find any among the examples or documentation. The `layout.api` only seems to order different elements, not change the orientation of a given element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation Link:
http://nucleic.github.io/enaml/docs/api_ref/widgets/slider.html#enaml.widgets.slider.Slider.orientation

Source Link:
https://github.com/nucleic/enaml/blob/master/enaml/widgets/slider.py#L104